# What does wait() do if the child calls exec?

Tags: c, process, exec

If a child calls exec it terminates and a new process is created with the same pid.

Would the wait() function wait for the child to terminate or the grandchild?

Comment: After the child calls `exec`, there's still the same child process ID, but a different program running — there is no grandchild process (yet).  Even if there is subsequently a grandchild because the child forks, the original process cannot wait for that grandchild; it can only wait for its own direct descendants, processes it creates itself via `fork()` (or perhaps `posix_spawn()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a child calls exec it terminates and a new process is created with the same pid.

No, not quite.

`exec` does not create a new process -- it overwrites a single process (the old process) with a new program.  So there's no new child (no "grandchild"), and no new pid.  So if the parent calls `wait`, it won't return until the `exec`'ed program does.  (In fact, `exec` doesn't have much of an external effect, that the parent could detect, at all.)